# How to compare two strings based on percent match in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to post a solution to a interesting problem I was facing in T-SQL.

The problem: 
Compare two string fields based on a **percent match**.
In addition, the two strings may have the words in them **translocated**.

For example: "Joni Bravo" and "Bravo Joni". These two strings should return a match of 100%, which means that position is not relevant. Few more things worth noting are that this code is made to compare strings that have space as delimiter in them. If the first string doesnt have space the match is set to 100% without actual check. This was not developed, because the strings this function is ment to compare always contain two or more words. Also, it is written on MS SQL Server 2017 if that mathers.

Comment: This is not really an appropriate use-case for SQL (although it *could* be done).  Have you looked into full text searches?

Comment: I did try to fiddle with full text and catalog type searches but it ultimately did not satisfy the needs of what i ment to do.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov Pretty useful! but have done a performance benchmarking like time vs number of records and vs number of words/length in string

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov I am almost certain that you can improve performance by using a Tally table instead of while loop

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Indeed, Tally tables are generally faster, i am just not that found of them and it would be harder for me :) anyone that can and wants should tweak this code for performance gains :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the solution, hope this helps anyone :)
gl

```
    /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[STRCOMP]    Script Date: 29/03/2018 15:31:45 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[STRCOMP] (
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
        @name_1 varchar(255),@name_2 varchar(255)
    )
    RETURNS float
    AS
    BEGIN
        

-- Declare the return variable and any needed variable here
    declare @p int = 0;
    declare @c int = 0;
    declare @br int = 0;
    declare @p_temp int = 0;
    declare @emergency_stop int = 0;
    declare @fixer int = 0;
    declare @table1_temp table (
    row_id int identity(1,1),
    str1 varchar (255));
    declare @table2_temp table (
    row_Id int identity(1,1),
    str2 varchar (255));
    declare @n int = 1;
    declare @count int = 1;
    declare @result int = 0;
    declare @total_result float = 0;
    declare @result_temp int = 0;
    declare @variable float = 0.0;
    
--clean the two strings from unwanted symbols and numbers

    set @name_1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@name_1,'!',''),'  ',' '),'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'0',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9','');
    set @name_2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@name_2,'!',''),'  ',' '),'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'0',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9','');

--check if the first string has more than one words inside. If the string does 
--not have more than one words, return 100%
set @c = charindex(' ',substring(@name_1,@p,len(@name_1)));


IF(@c = 0)
BEGIN
RETURN 100.00
END;

--main logic of the operation. This is based on sound indexing and comparing the 
--outcome. This loops through the string whole words and determines their soundex
--code and then compares it one against the other to produce a definitive number --showing the raw match between the two strings @name_1 and @name_2.
WHILE (@br != 2 or @emergency_stop = 20)
BEGIN

insert into @table1_temp(str1)
select substring (@name_1,@p,@c);
set @p = len(substring (@name_1,@p,@c))+2;
set @p = @p + @p_temp - @fixer;
set @p_temp = @p;
set @c = CASE WHEN charindex(' ',substring(@name_1,@p,len(@name_1))) = 0 THEN len(@name_1) ELSE charindex(' ',substring(@name_1,@p,len(@name_1))) END;
set @fixer = 1;
set @br = CASE WHEN charindex(' ',substring(@name_1,@p,len(@name_1))) = 0 THEN @br + 1 ELSE 0 END;
set @emergency_stop = @emergency_stop +1;
END;

set @p = 0;
set @br = 0;
set @emergency_stop = 0;
set @fixer = 0;
set @p_temp = 0;
set @c = charindex(' ',substring(@name_2,@p,len(@name_2)));

WHILE (@br != 2 or @emergency_stop = 20)
BEGIN

insert into @table2_temp(str2)
select substring (@name_2,@p,@c);
set @p = len(substring (@name_2,@p,@c))+2;
set @p = @p + @p_temp - @fixer;
set @p_temp = @p;
set @c = CASE WHEN charindex(' ',substring(@name_2,@p,len(@name_2))) = 0 THEN len(@name_2) ELSE charindex(' ',substring(@name_2,@p,len(@name_2))) END;
set @fixer = 1;
set @br = CASE WHEN charindex(' ',substring(@name_2,@p,len(@name_2))) = 0 THEN @br + 1 ELSE 0 END;
set @emergency_stop = @emergency_stop +1;
END;

WHILE((select str1 from @table1_temp where row_id = @n) is not null)
BEGIN
    set @count = 1;
    set @result = 0;
    WHILE((select str2 from @table2_temp where row_id = @count) is not null)
    BEGIN
        set @result_temp = DIFFERENCE((select str1 from @table1_temp where row_id = @n),(select str2 from @table2_temp where row_id = @count));
        IF(@result_temp > @result)
            BEGIN
                set @result = @result_temp;
                
            END;
            
        set @count = @count + 1;         
    END;
    
    set @total_result = @total_result + @result;
    set @n = @n + 1;
END;

--gather the results and transform them in a percent match.
set @variable = (select @total_result / (select max(row_count) from (
select max(row_id) as row_count from @table1_temp
union
select max(row_id) as row_count from @table2_temp) a));
RETURN @variable/4 * 100;

END
GO
```

PS: I decided to write it in a **user-defined function** just for the needs of my project.

Comment: I don't understand the output of this at all. It seems it will not go any lower than 50%? So things like "Bat man" and "xxx zzz" return 50%. How does that make sense? They share no common characters at all. This seems to be comparing characters instead of whole words. Is that on purpose? I don't understand the percentage result. Values like 'asdf cxxxccc', 'fdsa asdf' return 75%. I guess if it works for your situation that is great but this just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Hello @SeanLange. In order to understand how this comparison works, you should read about the built-in function **DIFFERENCE**. This code is based on it. Here is a link to the available documentation about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql hope this helps.